# Google Cloud Platform serving static sites over HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, https, static-site

I have multiple one page apps (static sites) in buckets on google cloud storage.
Each app can access the information it needs from one API running on a google app engine.

I can serve the one page apps by pointing the CName of each domain to c.google.storage.com, but it doesn't serve it over HTTPS, just HTTP.

My question is:

```
1) why does google storage not serve contents of buckets via HTTPS if I use a custom domain?
2) How can I serve content on google cloud storage via HTTPS?
```

NOTE: From my basic understanding of google load balancers, I can serve the content of buckets via HTTPS if I point the domain to the load balancer, but then I would need a load balancer for each app. Those load balancers are too expensive. Is it possible to have one load balancer for all apps maybe?

Comment: Yes, you can have one load balancer for several backends by proerly setting your backends configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a load balancer for each app. You can add multiple backends to a single load balancer and each backend can be connected to a separate storage bucket (that would be app specific). You can then add a hostname mapping on the load balancer per application, that will proxy requests to the correct backend bucket based on the Host-header in the request. You can also add path mapping to these rules if necessary.

Comment: Could you please explain this in more detail? I have 5 simple sites and each one has 2 load balancers...1 for serving my https site, and another for redirecting http to https. Are you saying that I can use 1 load balancer to redirect all http traffic for all my sites to each https site? This would be awesome because I've always thought paying for 2 load balancers per site was expensive for simple sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve with only one HTTPS load balancer. create the LB and add each storage bucket as a backend bucket in the loadbalancer. Don't forget to create your bucket with the DNS name (e.g bucket1.mycompany.com, bucket2.mycompany.com etc). Add a wildcard A record in your DNS entry pointing to external IP of LB.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe isn't the answer you are looking for, but I recommend Firebase Hosting (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) to host single-page sites (React, Vue, etc) on GCP.